# How to achieve the following in the RelativeLayout with 2 TextViews

Tags: android-layout, android-relativelayout, ellipsis

I have 2 TextViews on the same line located in a RelativeLayout **(see 1 green)**. Both texts are getting longer sometimes **(see 2 green)**. 
I would like to keep the width of the TextView on the left side dynamic and allow to expand if necessary. 
If the TextView on the left side expands to much by crossing the boundaries **(see 3 red)** of the TextView on the right side, than I would like to enable the ellipsis for the right TextView **(see 3 green)**.
[image]
When I try to fix the width of the second TextView it also may put the dots when the 1 case in the image applies, which is not necessary.